# ADDCOLUMNS alternate in powerpivot 2010

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

Can anybody please guide me theough. I am new to PowerPivot using 2010 addin. I cant find ADDCOLUMNS dax function which is available in powerpivot 2013. 
Please advise an alternate to this function for 2010. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like ADDCOLUMNS is not supported for PowerPivot 2010. Did you try this alternative ?

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg670985(v=office.14).aspx